# Publish build info from jfrog CLI to update Used By or Produce By info in tree browser in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

While publishing builds from TeamCity and checking the option of "Publish Build Info", I am able to see the "Produced By" and "Used By" entries in Artifactory. Is there any command so that I can also publish build info during local builds from jfrog CLI?

Answer (score 1):

There is no command yet that shows the build info before it is published. Feel free to create a GitHub issue in the [JFrog CLI](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go) repository, though. That will make sure the issue gets the attention of the team as an enhancement to the current project. If you create an issue, I'd vote for it because it is a good use case that I hadn't yet considered.